# Is it permitted to listen to Prank phone calls

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing, phone, hearing, onaath-devarim

Prank phone calls very often transgress the prohibiton of "gneivat daat" misrepresenting and Onaat Devarim causing anguish (Mishpatei Hashalom page 89). Is it permitted as a listener to derive benefit from these prank calls?

Does it matter if the caller or victim is a gentile? is there a problem of gneivat daat for a gentile?

Comment: Gneivas daas is assur even when concerning a gentile. Ch'm 228 6. Stealing so as to harass someone (i.e. you plan on returning it) is assur as a safeguard so as not to really steal, ch'm 348 1. I'm not sure if this applies to gentiles, it might depend on the Shach there #2 whether stealing from a gentile is not allowed Biblically or Rabbinicaly. Shach says Mechaber sounds like it's Biblical, so in all likelihood, the rabbinic enactment not to steal to harass would apply as well. But that siman is talking about stealing real money, so this may be an unjustified leap.

Comment: Is there onaas Devarim by a goy? Maybe darkei shalom.

Comment: I don't think deriving enjoyment from finding something humorous is technically prohibited as an *issur hana'a*, but I suppose there might be a different prohibition of *moshav leitzim* (joining a group of scoffers) or encouraging bad behavior or the like.